# Perl File::Find annoying issue

Tags: perl

I have a perl scripting issue which drivin me nutts. I wrote a script that uses File::Find module, which is supposed to walk recursively starting from given as an argument directory and perform a funcion on every single *.txt file that has been found. I simplified this problem to show only the main part.

To make it run and reproduce my problem we have to make a directory containing two files:
`fist.txt` and `second.txt` each having TWO LINES ONLY:

`cat fist.txt`:
`AAA`
`BBB`

`cat second.txt`:
`AAA`
`BBB`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use File::Find;

$ARGS_NUM = $#ARGV + 1;
if ($ARGS_NUM != 1) {
   print "Add start directory as an argument!\n";
   exit(-1);
}

my $DEST_DIR =$ARGV[0];    
find(\&splitter, $DEST_DIR);

sub splitter {
 if (-f $_ && /\.txt$/) {
    $DOC_FILE_NAME = $_;
    print "processing: $DOC_FILE_NAME\n";
    open $DOC_FILE, "<"."$DOC_FILE_NAME" or die "Could not open $DOC_FiLE\n";

    print "Entering first WHILE, DOC_FILE = $DOC_FILE\n";
    $AAA_FOUND = 0;
    $BBB_FOUND = 0;
    while(<$DOC_FILE>) {
      print "first_while\n";
      if (m/^AAA$/i) {
        print "FOUND: AAA in $DOC_FILE\n";
        $AAA_FOUND = 1;
        next;
      }

      if (m/^BBB$/i) {
        print "FOUND: BBB in $DOC_FILE\n";
        $BBB_FOUND = 1;
        next;
      }
    }
    #################### SECOND WHILE WCHICH FAILS.... #################
    $/="";
    seek $DOC_FILE,0,0;
    $QQQ_FOUND = 0;
    print "Entering second WHILE, DOC_FILE = $DOC_FILE\n";
    while(<$DOC_FILE>) {
      print "second_while\n";
      s/\n//g; s/$/\n/; s/^\s*//;
      if ($QQQ_FOUND == 1) {
        $question_text = $_;
        print "question_text = $question_text\n";
        last;
      }

      if (m/^QQQ.*$/i) {
        $QQQ_FOUND=1;
      }
    }
    $/ = undef;
    print "AAA = $AAA_FOUND\n";
    print "BBB = $BBB_FOUND\n";
    print "QQQ = $QQQ_FOUND\n";
    close $DOC_FILE;
  }
}
```

Here is the OUTPUT:

```
processing: first.txt
Entering first WHILE, DOC_FILE = GLOB(0x13087e0)
first_while
FOUND: AAA in GLOB(0x13087e0)
first_while
FOUND: BBB in GLOB(0x13087e0)
Entering second WHILE, DOC_FILE = GLOB(0x13087e0)
second_while
AAA = 1
BBB = 1
QQQ = 0
processing: second.txt
Entering first WHILE, DOC_FILE = GLOB(0x13087e0)
first_while
Entering second WHILE, DOC_FILE = GLOB(0x13087e0)
second_while
AAA = 0
BBB = 0
QQQ = 0
```

EDIT:
  As You can see second loop misses searching for values AAA and BBB.

Comment: Works fine when I run it.  Are you certain second.txt doesn't contain some sort of whitespace before or after the BBB?  And learn how to [`use strict`](https://metacpan.org/module/strict) and [`use warnings`](https://metacpan.org/module/warnings).

Comment: You probably have _something_ after that `BBB` in the second file that is neither the end of the line nor the end of the file... e.g. a space.

Comment: thanx mates, You were right, i edited my question to go on to the real problem i am facing with in this issue.. ;)

Comment: Add `use strict; use warnings;` to your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of people find `File::Find` annoying. It simply doesn't work as it should. It breaks good programming practices.

I find the best way to use it is to set a list variable outside of your *wanted* subroutine, and then use that to save the files that match your criteria. Then, you can return to your regular program for the actual work:

```
my @file_list;
find ( &wanted, $DEST_DIR);

sub wanted {
    next unless -f and  /\.txt$/;
    push @file_list, $File::Find::name;
}

# Now use @file_list to do what you need:
for my $file (@file_list) {
   yadda, yadda, yadda
}
```

Since the *wanted* function is so much shorter, you can combine the *wanted* function inside the `find` function:

```
find (
    sub {
          next unless -f and /\.txt$/;
          push @file_list, $File::Find::name;
       }, 
    $DEST_DIR
);
```

Comment: What good programming practice does it break? And, building up a list of potentially millions of files certainly isn't a good practice.

Comment: @briandfoy If you don't want to build a list of all files found, you're forced to put your entire program under your `wanted` subroutine. Your other choice is to put a list of your files found in an array variable, but that variable has to be _global_. That is, you use it in your `wanted` subroutine, but you have to declare your list variable outside of it. Yes, if you're looking through millions of files, building a list is not a great way, but most of the time, it's not bad. I like `File::Find::Object` a lot better, but it's not a standard package.

Comment: Oh c'mon, that's not true at all. I don't put my entire program inside the wanted function, and you know you're exaggerating there. At some point you have to deal with the individual file when you process it.

Comment: _At some point you have to deal with the individual files when you process it_: If I don't use an array to store files I want to handle, the only way to *deal* with the individual files is to put the needed logic *inside* `wanted`. `wanted` becomes my main program loop. My program could call a subroutine defined outside of `wanted`, but I could just as easily define that subroutine inside of `wanted` too. That's the only place where those subroutines are called. There maybe some initializations outside of `wanted` and maybe some post processing, but otherwise, my program is `wanted`.

Comment: Please post an answer on how you can use `File::Find` and not use an array to store the files or put the main program loop inside `File::Find`.

Comment: `$wanted = sub { process_file($_) }` Investigate the use of callbacks. I'm sure that most discussions of them will show you the patterns of programming. If you have a particular issue, ask a new question.

Answer (score 4):

Sure it does because you set `$/` to `undef` which enables slurp mode (meaning "read the whole file in a single call to `<>`). The default for `$/` is not `undef` but `"\n"`.

You should simply use `local $/;` instead of trying to reset it manually anyway.